# converting a data table operation to dataframe operation in r

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable

How do I convert this done in Data Tables into a R data frame operation:

```
     DT[, group_id := rleid(((v1 <95 | v2 <95))) ][]

        #group by group_id, only on rows where v1 or v2 > 110
        z<-DT[((v1 <95 |v2<95)), ][, .(start = min(timestamp),
                                                   end = max(timestamp),
                                                   duration = as.numeric(max(timestamp)-min(timestamp),units='mins')), 
                                                   by = .(group_id)][,group_id := 

NULL]
```

Sample data :

```
DT <- fread("timestamp              v1     v2
14-05-2019T04:28    112.2   111.0
14-05-2019T04:30    112.2   110.9
14-05-2019T04:39    101.4   101.8
14-05-2019T04:40    108.0   108.8
14-05-2019T04:45    101.1   101.5
14-05-2019T04:46    100.8   101.2
14-05-2019T05:32    111.6   111.5
14-05-2019T05:36    111.5   111.5
14-05-2019T05:39    111.5   111.5
14-05-2019T05:41    111.5   111.5
14-05-2019T05:46    111.5   111.4
14-05-2019T05:46    111.5   111.3
14-05-2019T05:47    111.5   111.3
14-05-2019T05:51    111.2   111.2
14-05-2019T05:56    111.2   111.2
14-05-2019T05:57    111.2   111.2")
```

I am trying to convert this into a more friendly code using dataframe, rather than using data table. How can I achieve it

Comment: Do you simply want to change DT to a dataframe? Then you can do as.data.frame().

Comment: There is not variable `v3` in the sample data you shared.

Comment: @sindri_baldur yes I know..I just added to show the structure of my data

Comment: @ChristofferSannes I want to have a data frame way of achieving the above task

Comment: @VictorJohnzon If your example is not reproducible much fewer people will bother to answer. Some tips here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example.

Comment: @sindri_baldur I removed the third condition

Comment: Now you have only 1 group .... Also `Error in max(timestamp) - min(timestamp) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator`